# Does 'meld' have a command-line style?

Tags: meld

Does meld support automatic merging ability, like 'kdiff3' does?

With kdiff3, you can do:

```
kdiff3 file1 file2 -o outfile
```

and do not have to open the GUI.

So can you do such with meld? I didn't find related topic in meld manual.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so.  You can use

```
meld file1 file2 --output=file3
```

to set the target file for saving a merge result, but it will still open the GUI (meld is after all a visual differ)